# New Occurrence Counting in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to  give unique number for unique column combination,for each new combination number has to increment by one

***`Sample Input`***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                'B':['a','a','b','a','a','a','a'],
                })

df

    A   B
0   A   a 
1   A   a 
2   A   b 
3   B   a 
4   B   a 
5   B   a
6   B   a
```

Desired Output

New Column 'C' with count by grouping values of column 'A' and 'B'  .
as below

```
   A   B  C
0   A   a  1
1   A   a  1
2   A   b  2
3   B   a  3
4   B   a  3
5   B   a  3
6   B   a  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.drop_duplicates().index, 'C'] = 1
df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  A  a  1
1  A  a  1
2  A  b  2
3  B  a  3
4  B  a  3
5  B  a  3
6  B  a  3
```

**Note:** this also works with two or more consecutive duplicated groups:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','B'],
                 'B':['a','a','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','a']})

df.loc[df.drop_duplicates().index, 'C'] = 1
df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  A  a  1
1  A  a  1
2  A  b  2
3  B  a  3
4  B  a  3
5  B  a  3
6  B  a  3
7  C  b  4
8  C  b  4
9  B  a  4
```

**Note 2:** Case above is also where `ngroup` method will not produce incrementing 'C' values, see the last row value (3) vs. the previous row (4):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','B'],
                 'B':['a','a','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','a']})

df['C'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).ngroup()+1
df
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  A  a  1
1  A  a  1
2  A  b  2
3  B  a  3
4  B  a  3
5  B  a  3
6  B  a  3
7  C  b  4
8  C  b  4
9  B  a  3
```

**Update:**

Similar to `ngroup` but with counting starting from the first occurrence:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','B'],
                 'B':['a','a','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','a']})

z = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
z['C'] = np.arange(len(z)) + 1
df = df.merge(z, how='left')
df
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  A  a  1
1  A  a  1
2  A  b  2
3  B  a  3
4  B  a  3
5  B  a  3
6  B  a  3
7  C  b  4
8  C  b  4
9  B  a  3
```

Comment: Thanks perl.About Index 9,it has to go with Value 3 of Column C.So its correct

Comment: Cool, yes, then `ngroup` is way to go

Comment: Counting is Starting from Ascending order of Alphabet,is it possible to avoid that,requirement is counting  has to start from first row.

Comment: Please see "Update" section of my answer

Answer (score 0):

using [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).ngroup()+1
```

Output

```
   A  B  C
0  A  a  1
1  A  a  1
2  A  b  2
3  B  a  3
4  B  a  3
5  B  a  3
6  B  a  3
```

Comment: Yes, good one. But this will factorize the groups so any same groups arriving after will have same value, dont know what the OP wants though. :)

Comment: ya i based it on that OP wants to count the group.. "New Column 'C' with count by grouping values of column 'A' and 'B' . as below"

Comment: I think there is a problem with this one as well, see "Note 2" in my answer

Comment: "How to give unique number for unique column combination" @perl that is one reason why eight row will have the same value becuase its not a unique combination right

Comment: @perl your note 1 answer gives it a 4 which i think is incorrect but lets see what OP wants..

Comment: Yes, but it's also stated in the question that "for each new combination number has to increment by one", so "a new combination" => +1, "not a new combination" => no change

Comment: how to define no change.. will get the same value before that or will it get the value for the same previous group.. i dont know.. as i said hope OP clarifies this.. @perl

Comment: Well yes maybe there is some ambiguity in the question, let's see :)